# Is this a coincidence?

Tags: geometry, limits, analytic-geometry

I was solving a problem and I noticed something which was very curious, the problem itself was easy:

> Find the point of intersection of the lines:
>   $$2x+3y=5$$ and
>   $$(1+c)x+(2+c)y=4+c$$  when c approaches 1.

I solved them and used the limit to get the point as $(-2,3)$ but also notice that for c very near to 1, the second equation is the same as the first! and also one thing that surprised me was that if I chose to put $c=0$, in the second equation, I get it as $$x+2y=4$$ and which remarkably has the same point of intersection with the first line as was when c approached 1. So my questions are

1.)Are these observations mere coincidences?

2.)Is there any geometric significance of these observations?

3.)And lastly, Suppose I had another function of c instead of the ones which I had in the second equation, example $$(1+c^2)x+(4-c^3)y=3+2c^2$$ and I had to find the point of intersection again and use $\lim_{c \to 1}$I don't get the same answer I get when I use $c=0$, (why does it work only for linear functions of c?)

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $c^2$ instead of $c^3$? Or did you just put $c$ in at random?

Comment: If c goes to one then both $c^2$ and $c^3$ go to 1 too, I wanted to just that so yeah, random.

Comment: @David K the constant doesn't go to 5  , I get the same answer for when I put c=1 in the equation and get an identical equation as the first.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood. The idea is that the equations of the two intersecting lines are identical if you set $c=1$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line $(1+c)x+(2+c)y-4-c=0$ is actually a combination of two lines because.
$$(1+c)x+(2+c)y-4-c=(x+2y-4)+\color{red}{c}(x+y-1)=0.$$
Thus for all values of $c$ it represents a line that passes through the intersection of the lines $x+2y-4=0$ and $x+y-1=0$ which is the point $(-2,3)$.

Comment: And this only works for those expressions in which c has the same degree on all three terms x,y and constant? so that it can be collected for forming two equations, is that correct?

Comment: @Nikunj yes that is correct.  In fact it need not be just a power term in $c$, you can use other functions of $c$ As well. The idea is that $c$ is being used as a parameter. So if $L_1$ is a line and $L_2$ is a line then as long as one of $m$ or $n$ is not $0$, the equation $mL_1+nL_2=0$ Is that if a line passing through the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$.

Answer (score 1):

From the setup of the question,
we have something resembling a system of two simultaneous
first-degree equations in $x$ and $y$
(equations of lines in the $x,y$ plane), except that the "constants"
of the second equation are all functions of some parameter $c$.
Moreover, if $c$ were set to $1$,
the two equations would describe the same line.

The question is, what constraints are there on the functions of $c$
if the point of intersection of the two lines as $c$ approaches $1$
must be the same as the point of intersection when $c=0$?

For the case where the functions are first-degree polynomials,
the two equations must fit the following form, where $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$,
$t$, $u$, and $v$ are all constants of our choosing:
\begin{align}
px + qy &= r \tag1\\
(sp + t(c - 1))x + (sq + u(c - 1))y &= sr + v(c - 1). \tag2
\end{align}

The reason for writing the equations this way is that equation $(2)$
has to become something of the form $spx + sqy = sr$ when $c=1$,
which accounts for the way $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$ occur in equation $(2)$,
while the "first-degree polynomial" allows us to add some multiple of
$c - 1$ (and nothing else) to each of the coefficients.

Equation $(1)$ implies that $spx + sqy$ and $sr$ are equal, so subtract
this quantity from the left and right sides of equation $(2)$ to produce
$$
t(c-1)x + u(c-1)y = v(c-1),
$$
so for whenever $c\neq 1$, we can cancel the common factor $c - 1$ to obtain
$$
tx + uy = v. \tag3
$$

So the simultaneous equations $(1), (2)$ imply the
simultaneous equations $(1), (3)$. If these have a unique solution,
that solution is also the solution of the system $(1), (2)$
whenever $c\neq 1$, so it's also the limit of the solution as
$c$ approaches $1$ and the value of the solution when $c = 0$.
And all of this is dictated by a few constraints we initially
put on these equations.

The same solution still works if we replace all the occurrences of
$c - 1$ in equation $(2)$ with some other function of $c$, as long
as we use the same function in all three places.
If we use different functions (not equal, and not constant multiples
of each other), then we lose equation $(3)$, and in the general case
the solution of the system $(1), (2)$ will vary as we vary $c$.

Note that we don't have to go to higher powers to make this happen:
if we change one of the $c-1$ functions to a *constant,* 
we can lose the fixed nature of the intersection point.
For example, if we make the coefficient of $x$ constant in equation $(1)$,
we cannot cancel common factors of $c-1$ and the best we can do
for equation $(3)$ is something like 
$$
tx + u(c-1)y = v(c-1).
$$
Except in some special cases, that makes the solution for the 
intersection point dependent on $c$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$2x+3y=5
$
and
$(1+c)x+(2+c)y=4+c
$,
subtracting
$\frac{1+c}{2}$ of the first
from the second,
$4+c-5\frac{1+c}{2}
=y((2+c)-3\frac{1+c}{2})
$
or
$\frac{2(4+c)-5(1+c)}{2}
=y\frac{2(2+c)-3(1+c)}{2}
$
or
$3-3c
=y(1-c)
$
or,
surprisingly,
$y = 3$
for all $c$.

Then
$x
=\frac{5-3y}{2}
=\frac{-4}{2}
=-2
$.

Therefore
the second line
passes through
$(-2, 3)$
for all $c$
as does the first.

Note that
when $c=1$
 the two lines are the same.

Comment: I know that, but my question is about c as well, why only linear terms of c in the expression work?